# Echo Statement add plus

Tags: php

How do I alter this echo statement to insert a plus where there is currently a space?

```
<?php echo(str_replace('"', '&quot;', $row_WADAsarenewals['CityStZip'])); ?>
```

Comment: str_replace() will take an array for the find and replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php echo(str_replace(' ', '+', $row_WADAsarenewals['CityStZip'])); ?>
```

But if you need to use multiple matches and multiple replacements, try using arrays for the "needles" and arrays for the "replacements"... as discussed in the `str_replace` doc examples: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php